# PHP email not working, message not in email body

Tags: php, html, email

I had put up a few questions related but i wasn't clear enough. I am sending an email through an html form. With this code when I send it the title and from wrk, but there is no message body. Here is the html:

```
    <html> <body><form method="post" action="contact.php">
 Email: <input name="email" type="text"><br> name:<br> 
<textarea name="name" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br> 
Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit"> </form> <body> <html>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php    

$headers=  
"BCC: " . $_POST['email'];
$headers .= "BCC: ".$to_visitor."\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: Your Company <your_company@example.com>\r\n";

$header1 = " ";
$header2 = " ";

$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
$thank_you = " ".$common_data;

mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $thank_you, $header2); ?>
```

I just don't know what the problem is. Thank you in advance. All help is appreciated 
-Ben

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_POST)` to check so the `message` isn't empty?

Comment: How would I use that?? Sorry, I am a total noob

Comment: Just add a `var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);` statement at the top of your script. This will show you the content of the array.

Comment: Add `print_r($_POST);` after the `<?php ` tag. Also you should move `$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];` before the $headers line, else it won't ever be sent via BCC. Actually you don't need `$headers .= "BCC: ".$to_visitor."\r\n";` as you are already doing it in a line before that.

Comment: when I try that, the message works, but it's from "a7269592@srv15.000webhost.com" how could I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me. I did small modifications to your code. Please try. Your code is not in correct flow anyway.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

 $headers = "From: Your Company <your_company@example.com>\r\n";


$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];

mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);

} ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<html> <body><form method="post" >
 Email: <input name="email" type="text"><br> name:<br> 
<textarea name="name" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br> 
Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit"> </form> <body> <html>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Action not require if you POST to the same page.